# QGIS: Prevent numbers and their units being split across rows

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, display

The correct convention for displaying measurements in text is to have a space between the number and the unit such as 10 m.
When **presenting attribute tables, in a layout for example** the "m" often gets split onto a new line if you have fixed column widths. Is there a way to keep the number and its unit together?

As shown below, the second row doesn't look great.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a visual example? This isn't a problem I have ever experienced.

Comment: You have an attribute table that contains not only numbers, but also characters ? That makes no sense to me as you would need to format the field as a text (string) field and then, mathematical operations or sorting would not work properly. Best practice would be to keep field content simple and only have numbers. Where do you need to include the `m`? In a print layout? There, you can use expressions to add the `m` to the field value and format it the way you need. So your question does not make sense to me or you should make it clearer where exactly you need this and what are your settings.

Comment: The attribute is a text description it could have multiple references to measurements. such as "clear branches to 2 m from the road up to 3 m heigh" or none depending on what work is required. As far as I am aware using text strings for descriptive text is not really bad practice.

Comment: OK, so in the attribute table, it looks correct? So where does the plroblem appear? Sorry, it's difficult to understand the problem if you don't provide the context. It could have many different causes, so adding as much relevant information as possible is crucial.

Comment: I meant a visual example of it happening in your attribute table. Not to address this specific problem, but another option could be to use an integer field (which is easier to perform calculations on if needs be) and append the ' m' wherever it is needed in maps/reports etc.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking: I mean in your case, the width of the column is too small to show the whole text. You're not asking about that, are you? I mean drawing the broder of the column a bit to the right to make a larger width could solve that issue.

Comment: Some of the descriptions get quite long so the  rows have to be multi-line and it has to fit to a page width

Comment: You want rows to bo multiline, but want to avoid line breaks...? Are you asking about Non-breaking space inside a table element in print layout, showing the content of the attribute table? If so, you should make that clear. I really struggle to understand where in QGIS you are - for you it maybe seems more than obvious, but for people reading your questions, it is not, it could be anything...

Comment: Apologies "Presenting attribute tables" may not have been clear enough. Yes to non-breaking spaces - however you achieve that?

Comment: non-breaking spaces : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: What does you screenshot show? It does not look like the default attribute table view in QGIS. The attribute table in QGIS has flexible column widths and I don't see a use case where you use it for presenting your results. However, you can still replace the space before "m" with a no-break space (e.g. copy&paste it from an external editor using the input methods described in @J.R's link) manually or using `replace()` with a regular expression. If you are talking about a representation of the attribute table contents e.g. in a print layout, you have more options.

Comment: @Sethinacan Sorry, without providing the clarifications many people are asking for, I fear you won't get an appropriate answer to your question. This site is about giving answers to clear questions, not guessing what the question was.

Comment: @Babel I have been out of the office, I think the answer is a non breaking space. The question is a about presenting long descriptive text in attribute tables (in a layout for example) in multi line tables. The descriptive text comes both from a value relation (easy to fix) and from free text which I will have to write an expression for as I don't see surveyors putting in a NBS on an iPad in the field. The expression will have to look for a number followed by a space and an m the replaced the space with a NBS. Should be fine. I added an image to show what's going as described in my question

Comment: So you are not talking about necessarily replacing the normal space by a non-breaking space in the attribute table itself, but in a graphical representation of the table, e.g. in a layout. Correct? The main source of misunderstanding here is that what is generally referred to as the "attribute table" in QGIS is only what you get e.g. by double-clicking a vector layer. The term is normally not used for any other (graphical) representations of the attribute data e.g. in layouts, even when presented as a table.

Comment: With regards to non-breaking spaces, take a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797208/4227297). I just tested with the last one on the list (`U+202F`  Narrow No-Break Space) and it appears to have the effect you want.

Comment: Char 0160 seems to work. regexp_replace("fieldname", '(\\d+) \\s(m)', '\\1' || char(160) || '\\2')

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you defined the value and where you use it, you might have accidentally entered a space for Wrap on character that converts the space into a line break:

*The label is generated here with the expression `value || ' m'`, where value is the field containing a number. So the label would look like `1.6 m`, however, when a space is entered in the `Wrap on character` box, you will get a new line instead of the space. As the space is invisible, this can generate confusion.*
[image]

Comment: The question is about attribute tables

Comment: So the line break is in the attribute table itself? Can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a linebreak in a textfield in the attribute table, you can remove it by either manually delete it or use field calculator with this expression:

`replace ("field_name" ,'\n' ,' ')`

It replaces a line brake ("New line" marker '\n') with a space.

[image]

Comment: There are no line breaks in the text

Comment: So then what is the problem? I thought you wanted to get rid of line breaks? Maybe I don't understand the question...

Comment: @Sethinacan, do not be rude. Babel does his best to help you based on all the details you provided :)

Comment: @Taras being concise may be interpreted as rude when that is not the intention