# Replacing spaces between a number and its unit using regexp_replace

Tags: qgis, regular-expression

In QGIS attributes I have text strings that sometimes include a measurement as part of descriptions, "such as cut at 10 m". In order to make these look nice when presented in multiline fixed width tables in a layout I would like to replace the spaces with non breaking spaces.
I think  regexp_replace is the best tool but I have struggled to find a guide to creating the regular expression I can understand.
the units are always m so any occurrences of **number space m**  can be replaced with **number NBS m** this could potentially find a some instances that shouldn't be replaced (such as "near house 21 melted snow is") but they are unlikely  to be an issue.

Comment: Since you are having trouble, you seem to have tried something already - what did you try, and how does the result not suit your needs? Also, please provide the exact settings of your layout, including limiting factors which must be kept in mind when creating the labels.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous Question, but without the useful graphic  [QGIS: Prevent numbers and their units being split across rows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471178/qgis-prevent-numbers-and-their-units-being-split-across-rows)

Comment: Are decimals ever a possibility or are you fortunate enough to work in a world of only whole numbers?  Existing answers won't address possibility of decimals.

Comment: Fortunately in this instance the numbers are always integers, so the solution is a bit niche.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an expression like:

```
regexp_replace("fieldname", '(\\d+) m', '\\1 m')
```

This replaces any **number space m** (any positive number of digits) with **number NBS m**, as requested.

The "space" between `\\1` and `m` in the second string needs to be a non-breaking space character. In Windows, you can hold down the Alt key and type `0160` on the numeric keypad to get this.

As per Vincé's suggestion, you can also use char(160) to create the non-breaking space eg:

```
regexp_replace( "fieldname" , '(\\d+)\\s(m)', '\\1' || char(160) || '\\2')
```

In the screenshot below, the first line has non-breaking spaces in both columns. The second line has a normal space in the first column, and a non-breaking space in the second. The second column has been created and used in the expression above and run on the first column using the Field Calculator.

[image]

Comment: I think in QGIS expressions, you can denote a non-breaking space using "char(160)" so **regexp_replace("fieldname", '(\\d+) \\s(m)', '\\1' || char(160) || '\\2')** should do the trick.

Comment: I have struggled to find a guide to the form of the regular expression required so this helps quite a bit in seeing what is going on

Comment: I found the following link useful in understanding the expressions provided https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Cheatsheet

Comment: @Sethinacan, QGIS regular expressions are based on Qt's [QRegularExpression Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html), so I encourage you to use that as a reference since different flavors of regex have different implementations.

Comment: @bixb0012 I did find that link when hunting, it is a more definitive source but probably a bit more use once I have got my head around what you can do with regular expressions.